# Go modulesでbuild時にcannot find packageというエラーが表示される

Tags: go

./goexample
./goexample/main.go
./goexample/config
./goexample/config/config.go

のような階層で、main.goからconfigパッケージであるconfig.goを呼び出し使用しております。
config.goは`"gopkg.in/ini.v1"`をインポートしております。

[Go Modules](https://qiita.com/propella/items/e49bccc88f3cc2407745)を参考に以下のような過程で実行したところエラーが発生しました。

```
$go mod init goexample
$cd config/
$go mod init config
$go get -u gopkg.in/ini.v1
$cd ..
$go build ./...
```

**発生エラー**
`config/config.go:インポート行番号: cannot find package`
以上のようなパッケージiniをインポートする場所でエラーが起こっております。これはmodulesを使用してどのようにGoパッケージiniをインストールすれば良いでしょうか。

./goexample/main.go

```
package main
import(
 "./config"
)
//code
```

./goexample/config/config.go

```
package config
import (
    "gopkg.in/ini.v1" <-エラー発生箇所
)
//code
```

の様にしております。
OSはFedoraを使用しております。

Answer (score 0):

ディレクトリ内において以下の要領で実施。

```
$go mod init goexample
$go run main.go 
$go get -u gopkg.in/ini.v1
$go run main.go
```

またmain.go内のimport箇所を

```
import(
 "goexample/config"
)
```

の様に変更する。